# Log4net - delete any logs that is over 14 days old

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, rollingfileappender

I am creating a logger by using log4net's RollingFileAppender.
One feature that I need to provide is to delete any logs that is over 14 days old.

How is that possible with using log4net's RollingFileAppender?

Thanks.

Comment: Note also this is a [long standing issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-27)

Comment: Nov - 2021 - the issue remains

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try this

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value=".\Logs\" />
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="'On_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="14" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: So what it does is create the backup file with the name `"'On_'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'"`, but still uses roll backups? (since `maxSizeRollBackups` is set to 14). If this is the case, it might be also good to add `<maximumFileSize value="1024KB" />` to customize the size of each roll backup.

Comment: I need to roll a backup for every session.
Hence, the rollingStyle value must be set to "Once".