# Log4net is not removing old files

Tags: c#, log4net

Please read through question before marking it as duplicate.  I have gone through the [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31483089/log4net-delete-any-logs-that-is-over-14-days-old) in this forum but could not find the solution working.

Please refer to my configurtion below

```
<log4net>
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}\FileManager\Logs\Log_" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <datePattern value="MMddyyyy'.log'" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <preserveLogFileNameExtension value="true" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="3" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] – %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
<root>
  <level value="ALL"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
<logger>
  <level />
  <appender-ref />
</logger>
```

I ran my application for more than 3 days but it didn't remove old log files.  My screenshot of logs

[image]

Comment: This is a known (unresolved) issue. See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95286/log4net-set-max-backup-files-on-rollingfileappender-with-rolling-date) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259795/can-log4net-delete-log-files-automatically) SO post.

Comment: @CodeCaster, I believe marking a question duplicate with a solution provided 6 years ago is not a correct approach; From this action, it implies that users are restricted from asking questions that may otherwise be possible with new versions in the industry or latest approaches;

Comment: @techspider on the other hand, we also don't need yearly _"Is this still broken?"_ - _"Yes"_ Q&As. If you disagree, feel free to start a discussion on [meta] (but not before searching). The point is: the answer in the duplicate is still valid, but because the same question gets asked and answered (incorrectly) over and over again, it becomes impossible to find the actual answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster, which namespace has LogManager in that code?  I have my own LogManager class and not able to find in Log4net namespaces

Comment: [`log4net.LogManager`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_LogManager_GetLogger_2.htm)